# Gruntfile start server, autoreload, auto open in broswer

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, package.json

Hey guys I am new to gruntfile and front end dev in general, I am trying to set up gruntfile so that it will run a server from my default task, this actually works but it does not open at index.htmt but on `Grunt-Serve page` instead then i have to navigate to src/index.html.

my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    serve: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            hostname: 'localhost',
        }
    }
  });

  //Load Grunt serve task
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-serve');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['serve']);

};
```

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-serve": "^0.1.6"
  }
```

also i have seen before that it is possible to use gruntfile or the serve task to auto open the project in a browser... package I would need for this....? and also once am developing i would like to see my changes live.

Any help appricated

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for browser-sync. It normally opens the browser automatically. You can see some configuration examples here: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt

But just to get you started, try this setup:

First run `$ npm install grunt-browser-sync --save-dev`

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    browserSync: {
      bsFiles: {
        src : [
          'index.html',
          'paths/to/files/for/autoreload'
        ]
      },
      options: {
        server: {
          baseDir: "./"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync']);
};
```

The baseDir will try to open any file named index.html in the directory you specify, but I'm pretty sure you can configure this too. You can also change the file structure as you like and adapt the config.

Add the paths in `src` that you would like to watch and auto reload. Please note you might need to have a look at the other examples if you combine this with sass or other preprocessors.